# Why isn't the test in my jQuery filter function working as expected?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I used a function in filter to check whether the display mode is block but it's not working.

Here's my code:

```
$("#wrap_element").find("*").filter(function(){
    return this.css("display")==="block";
}).css("background-color","red");
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) so you know how this site works.

Answer (score 3):

You have a console error that hints at the problem:

> Uncaught TypeError: this.css is not a function

You need to use a jQuery object since you're calling a jQuery method on it:

```
return $(this).css("display")==="block";
// ----^^----^
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/rnzdj3kb/4)

Comment: This is correct. To use a jQuery function like `css()`, you first need a jQuery object. `this` by itself is not a jQuery object. If you call `$(this)`, you get back a jQuery object which has functions like `css()` on its prototype.